# Elixir without prefixing functions with module?

Tags: elixir

I looked at some Elixir projects, and saw code like that:

```
value = Dict.get(options, :key)
```

Is there a way to make it shorter and leverage the 
dispatching/protocols? It seems like there are some statements like 
`import`, `use`, `require` in Elixir.

So it seem like it should be possible to write short code and let 
the compiler to figure out should it use Dict.get or String.get:

```
import Dict, String

# Getting :key from the Dict.
value = get options, :key

# Getting the second char from the String
char = get "some-string", 2
```

Does such approach works in Elixir? I.e. is it possible to write short
and compact code instead of long fully prefixed names like 
`A.B.C.do_something`?

Comment: What you want is type-inference. Even in languages that support that (ML family languages mainly) type annotations are sometimes necessary.  What I mean to say is even in a type-inferred language you may have to sometimes do something analogous to Dict.get or String.get.  Also, while shorter code is a good goal, other developers being able to read your code is also an important goal. Forcing disambiguation is not entirely a bad thing from that point of view.

Comment: This is not always a good idea, it makes your code shorter, but when you come back to it 6 months later it makes it that much harder to figure out, because you run into the case of where the ???? was that function defined

Answer (score 4):

You can definately write short,compact code using **alias**. Just make sure you dont confuse yourself. Check the [offical documentation](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html#alias)

```
iex(1)> alias Enum, as: E
nil
iex(2)> E.reduce [1,2,3,4], &(&1+&2)
10
```

As for the first part of your question. When you import modules, conflicts will show ambiguous error.For example

```
iex(1)> import Map, only: [delete: 2]
iex(5)> delete %{a: 4,b: 5}, :a
iex(6)> import List, only: [delete: 2]
iex(8)> delete %{a: 4,b: 5}, :a       
** (CompileError) iex:8: function delete/2 imported from both List and Map, call is ambiguous
    (elixir) src/elixir_dispatch.erl:111: :elixir_dispatch.expand_import/6
    (elixir) src/elixir_dispatch.erl:82: :elixir_dispatch.dispatch_import/5
```

So make sure you import only useful functions from a module.using the `only` keyword. Another good option would be to take advantage of lexical scoping in [import](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html#import). Where you can specify where you want to use the imports and only that part will be effected. Here is an example

```
defmodule Math do
  def some_function do
    import List, only: [duplicate: 2]
    duplicate(:ok, 10)
  end

  def other_function do
    duplicate(:ok, 10)#this will show error since import is only present inside some_function
  end
end
```

Alternatively [protocol](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/protocols.html) could be thing you are looking for.The docs will tell you what you need to know, i'l put up a short summary here.

```
defprotocol Get do
  @doc "Returns the data,for given key"
  def get(data,key)
end
```

You can then implement it for whatever type you require

```
defimpl Get, for: Map do
  def get(data,key), do: Map.get(data,key)
end

defimpl Get, for: Keyword do
  def get(data,key), do: Keyword.get(data,key)
end

defimpl Blank, for: Any do
  def blank?(data,key), do: raise(ArgumentError, message: "Give proper type for key")
end
```

Comment: Sad, I was afraid it works that way. The `alias` doesn't solve the problem, I want to use Polymorphism (or the Method Dispatching / Protocols as it's called in FP). The important thing is that I would like to be free from remembering if I should get the "get" method from Enum (or E) or from Dict (or D).

Comment: i am kinda sure that wont be possible in elixir since its a dynamic type language so all types in Elixir are inferred by at the runtime. But there is stuff called protocols and it can work you. http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/protocols.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. Although it seems strange that people don't use Protocols..., I've checked couple of repositories and it seems like all of them are using `A.B.C.some_function` expressions.

Comment: A.B.C.some_function is nesting of modules. http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html#nesting

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a combination of import :only with import :except to get the behavior you're looking for. Check [here](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html#import) for more details.

---

EDIT:

Another possible approach occurs to me.  You could also create a shorter name via an anonymous function.  Something like this:

```
dget = &(Dict.get/2)

sget = &(String.get/2)
```

Then your sample code would look like this:

```
value = dget.(options, :key)

char = sget.("some-string", 2)
```

While this would, of course, work I think it's probably still not what you're looking for.  I add this to my answer solely for others who may run across this Q & A to help to give a more complete answer about possible alternatives.